# android how to plot the graph from a bezier curve equation

Tags: android, graph, plot, equation, bezier

How can I plot the graph from the cubic bezier curve equation?I tried using cubicTo function in android but the thing is after the graph is drawn I will be drawing on top of that graph and I need to calculate whether the points are on the plotted curve or not.so i cant use cubicTo function.Is there any way I can do that.Any ideas or comments will be much appreciated,thanks a bunch.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html

Comment: Just implement your own cubic bezier. Google will give you lots of reference implementations, including java.